# Modified Mendelian Ratios Problem

Tags: genetics

I'm studying modified Mendelian ratios. I've got a theoretical problem that I'm stumped on:

A species of bird may have normal wings, or a mutation that causes frazzled wings.

I do 15 identical breeding pairs, crossing a male bird with frazzled wings to a normal winged female. The progeny obtained are 46 with normal wings (22 male/24 female) and 23 frazzled, all male.

Afterwards, I mate the normal winged females to the normal winged males obtained from the above cross. The progeny obtained all have normal wings.

I figured out a possible solution, and would like to know if it makes sense:

`Z(f)` = Z sex chromosome with normal wing gene, recessive
`Z(F)` = Z sex chromosome with frazzled wing gene, dominant
`W` =  W sex chromosome

- `Z(F)/W` = abnormal wing female bird (does not survive as not enough
  gene product produced)
- `Z(f)/W` = normal wing female bird
- `Z(F)/Z(F)` = abnormal wing male bird (does not survive as not enough gene product produced, or possibly survives as just enough is produced by 2 mutant genes, doesn't matter anyway)
- `Z(F)/Z(f)` = abnormal wing male bird (survives as wildtype gene produces enough product)
- `Z(f)/Z(f)` = normal winged male bird

My crosses:

P1: `Z(F)/Z(f) × Z(f)/W` 
Progeny: `Z(F)/Z(f)`, `Z(f)/Z(f)`, `Z(F)/W` (fails to survive), `Z(f)/W`

F1: `Z(F)/Z(f)`, `Z(f)/Z(f)`, `Z(f)/W` in 2:1 normal:frazzled wings 
F2: `Z(f)/Z(f) × Z(f)/W` produces `Z(f)/Z(f)`, `Z(f)/W`

---

This would account for the phenotypic ratios seen in the problem, and also uses the `ZW` sex chromosome system found in birds. The genetic explanation would be that a single `Z(F)` does not produce enough product to thrive, for whatever reason. The trait is sex-linked dominant on the Z chromosome.

Comment: Can you shorten your question. Just keep the latest part that you want to ask with minimum required background.